# DKIM Info missing from Mailguns website

Tags: mailgun, dkim

I need to add the DKIM key from mailgun.org to our DNS provider due to AOL and Yahoo rejected our messages because the from address has our domain and the sending server is mailgun.

DMARC is implemented by yahoo and aol so I was told that was the only way, on the mailgun website the DKIM key isn't listed under the SPF record like it shows in their documentation, it is just missing.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem, all the domains I have in there get generated without DKIM, only one SPF record but no TXT/DKIM record. Lame. Did  you find a fix?

Comment: I forget what they had me do but I contacted mailgun support and they were able to help me out.

Comment: Yeah, they don't generate them for subdomains unless you call and request them to. After my phone call, subsequent subdomains had them generate just fine. Lame though. Failing startup I say.